# Problem with Jython urllib2.urlopen for HTTPS pages

Tags: jython

I have a python program using urllib2 to GET a page via https protocol:

```
urllib2.urlopen('https://mywebsite')
```

I have no problem running this script using python interpreter, but when running with Jython interpreter, I got this error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error (-1,'SSL handshake exception')>
```

Do I need to do something else to make `urllib2.urlopen` work with an https address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Jython use the Java SSL implementation, so you'll need to add the server's certificate to your keystore. That's because Java always checks the certificate validity. 
[Installing a certificate](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Security6.html)
And two ways of not checking the validity, [with java code](http://jython.xhaus.com/installing-an-all-trusting-security-provider-on-java-and-jython/) and [pure Jython](http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/).

Comment: link for pure jython is dead :(

Comment: still can be found in archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20151018070137/http://tech.pedersen-live.com:80/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/