# How can one download an https file with Jython 2.x without ignoring ssl validation?

Tags: https, jython

I'm using Jython 2.latest and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to *securely* (i.e. not turning off verification) to download an HTTPS link.

All I can seem to find are examples where you turn off validation.

I'm using code like

```
  thefile = urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/index.php")
  with open(save_path, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(thefile.read())
    logging.info("Successfully downloaded %s", save_path)
```

But I get a handshake error, totally expected.

So I've generated the ssl cert:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >example.pem`

So now I have the PEM file. Now what do I do, does anyone know? Am I stuck installing the PEM file into the keystore?

Link here: [Problem with Jython urllib2.urlopen for HTTPS pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500010/problem-with-jython-urllib2-urlopen-for-https-pages) says that you can only add it to the java keystore.